# Create a table from max and min values in another

Tags: mysql, max, min, create-table

I have table with Name|ValueA|ValueB.1|ValueB,2 where Name is not unique.

I want to extract the B.1 and B.2 values for the low and high A vales for each name.

- **Bob|1|200|205**
- Bob|2|500|625
- **Bob|7|450|850**
- Bob|3|644|125|
- **Ann|4|120|120**
- Ann|8|451|191
- **Ann|9|145|982**

I want a new table with unique names with high and low ValueA, ValueB.1, ValueB.2

- Bob|1|7|200|450|205|850
- Ann|4|9|120|145|120|982

I remember there is some way to use min/max but am not sure how to set up the query to extract the new table.

Comment: I see "I want..." a couple times, but no instances of "I've tried…"

Comment: If you had `Ann, 8, 451, 1000`, all other records being the same, what would the resultset look like?

Comment: @PatrickQ Because as stated I do not know how to construct the query with min/max. Is this a finals test where I need to show my work? I think the question is clearly stated.

Comment: @Quassnoi the result set would look the same as in the example. I am not looking for high ValueBs, but the ValueBs from the high and loaw Value A records.  Good question though thanks

Comment: If you're not willing to show some effort, you're going to find that you're not going to get a lot of quality answers here. This is not a place to come and ask people to do your work for you. Do some basic research, make an attempt, and if it fails, _then_ ask a question and include what you've tried. If you don't know about then `min()` and `max()` functions, then [read the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max)

Comment: @PatrickQ However I *did* get a quality answer (see below) and however I did read the manual and could not figure out how to construct the query. Thus the question minus superfluous steps or 'proof of work'.

Answer (score 2):

```
    INSERT newtable (Name, ValueA, ValueB.1, ValueB.2)
      SELECT Name,MAX(ValueA),MIN(ValueA),MAX(ValueB.1),MIN(Value B.1),
        MAX(ValueB.2),MIN(ValueB.2)
      FROM oldtable GROUP BY Name
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing Create New Table as (Select Name, Max(ValueA), Min(ValueA), etc from oldtable Group by Name) and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that values of `A` are distinct (at least within a `name`):

```
INSERT
INTO    newtable
SELECT  name, mmin.a, mmax.a, mmin.b1, mmin.b2, mmax.b1, mmax.b2
FROM    (
        SELECT  name, MIN(a) mina, MAX(a) maxa
        FROM    mytable
        GROUP BY
                name
        ) md
JOIN    mytable mmin
ON      (mmin.name, mmin.a) = (md.name, md.mina)
JOIN    mytable mmax
ON      (mmin.name, mmin.a) = (md.name, md.maxa)
```